# Typeahead/Bloodhound isn't showing any results

Tags: javascript, html, typeahead.js

I'm having problems with Bloodhound, as it won't show any search results.

Here's my JS code:

```
var searchitems = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: function(d) {
          return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
      },
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
     filter: function (searchitems) {
        // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
        return $.map(searchitems, function (item) {
            return {
                value: item.name
            };
        });
    },
      // url points to a json file that contains an array of country names, see
      // https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/countries.json
      prefetch: {
            url: '../assets/js/crops.json'
        }
    });

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
searchitems.initialize();

$('#prefetch').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'prefetch',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: searchitems.ttAdapter()
});
```

And my HTML code, if that's the problem:

`<input class="typeahead" id="prefetch" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Search">`

You can see it doesn't seem to work here: https://cyalins.github.io/stardew

I have no idea why it's not working, and I've checked pretty much every tutorial and resource I could find, so I hope someone can figure it out!

Comment: your prefetch url is definitely accurate? are you able to log an object or any results to the console?

Comment: The crops.json is definitely loading up, and I just tried using console.log(searchitems) but it doesn't seem to give any useful information; just a bunch of weird arrays